# How to align C++ member access continuation on column?

Tags: c++, code-formatting, uncrustify

How can I configure, if possible, Uncrustify to format the following code

```
MyObject obj;
obj.a_func_returning_another_object().get_a_pointer_function()->do_stuff();
AnotherObject* objPointer = new AnotherObject();
anObject->fooObj().barMember().done();
```

like this?

```
MyObject obj;
obj.a_func_returning_another_object()
   .get_a_pointer_function()
   ->do_stuff();
AnotherObject* objPointer = new AnotherObject();
anObject->fooObj()
        .barMember()
        .done();
```

Especially, if the source member name (in this case `obj`) varies?

Using `indent_member=N` always indents by `N` spaces, which does not take the source member's name into account.

*Bonus*: Can this line-breaking behavior be configured to only take action if the `code_width` option forces a line break?

Comment: I suppose one person's "beautification" is another person's ugly stick.

Comment: I can't deny that. ;-)